# logstash error : Error registering plugin, Pipeline aborted due to error (<TypeError: can’t dup Fixnum>)

Tags: logstash, logstash-jdbc

I'm a beginner on ELK and trying to load data from MySQL to elasticsearch(for next step I want to query them via javarestclient), so I used logstash-6.2.4 and elasticsearch-6.2.4. and followed an [example](https://qbox.io/blog/migrating-mysql-data-into-elasticsearch-using-logstash) here.
when I run: `bin/logstash -f /path/to/my.conf`, I got the error:

```
[2018-04-22T10:15:08,713][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] Error registering plugin {:pipeline_id=>"main", :plugin=>"<LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc jdbc_connection_string=>\"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb\", jdbc_user=>\"root\", jdbc_password=><password>, jdbc_driver_library=>\"/usr/local/logstash-6.2.4/config/mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar\", jdbc_driver_class=>\"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver\", statement=>\"SELECT * FROM testtable\", id=>\"7ff303d15d8fc2537248f48fae5f3925bca7649bbafc30d2cd52394ea9961797\", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>\"plain_f8d44c47-8421-4bb9-a6b9-0b34e0aceb13\", enable_metric=>true, charset=>\"UTF-8\">, jdbc_paging_enabled=>false, jdbc_page_size=>100000, jdbc_validate_connection=>false, jdbc_validation_timeout=>3600, jdbc_pool_timeout=>5, sql_log_level=>\"info\", connection_retry_attempts=>1, connection_retry_attempts_wait_time=>0.5, last_run_metadata_path=>\"/Users/chu/.logstash_jdbc_last_run\", use_column_value=>false, tracking_column_type=>\"numeric\", clean_run=>false, record_last_run=>true, lowercase_column_names=>true>", :error=>"can't dup Fixnum", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x3fae16e2 run>"}
[2018-04-22T10:15:09,256][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline aborted due to error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<TypeError: can't dup Fixnum>, :backtrace=>["org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1882:in `dup'", "uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/date/format.rb:838:in `_parse'", "uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/date.rb:1830:in `parse'", "/usr/local/logstash-6.2.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/value_tracking.rb:87:in `set_value'", "/usr/local/logstash-6.2.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/value_tracking.rb:36:in `initialize'", "/usr/local/logstash-6.2.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/value_tracking.rb:29:in `build_last_value_tracker'", "/usr/local/logstash-6.2.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:216:in `register'", "/usr/local/logstash-6.2.4/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:342:in `register_plugin'", "/usr/local/logstash-6.2.4/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:353:in `block in register_plugins'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in `each'", "/usr/local/logstash-6.2.4/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:353:in `register_plugins'", "/usr/local/logstash-6.2.4/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:500:in `start_inputs'", "/usr/local/logstash-6.2.4/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:394:in `start_workers'", "/usr/local/logstash-6.2.4/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:290:in `run'", "/usr/local/logstash-6.2.4/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:250:in `block in start'"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x3fae16e2 run>"}
[2018-04-22T10:15:09,314][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:id=>:main, :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Could not execute action: LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, action_result: false", :backtrace=>nil}
```

here is the testdbinit.conf(utf-8 encoding):

```
input {
  jdbc { 
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb"
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => "mypassword"
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/local/logstash-6.2.4/config/mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM testtable"
    }
  }
output {
  stdout { codec => json_lines }
  elasticsearch {
  "hosts" => "localhost:9200"
  "index" => "testdemo"
   document_id => "%{personid}"
  "document_type" => "person"
  }
}
```

here is the table（database:testdb--->table:testtable）:

```
mysql> select * from testtable;
+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------+
| PersonID | LastName | FirstName | City      | flag  |
+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------+
|     1003 | McWell   | Sharon    | Cape Town | exist |
|     1002 | Baron    | Richard   | Cape Town | exist |
|     1001 | Kallis   | Jaques    | Cape Town | exist |
|     1004 | Zhaosi   | Nicholas  | Iron Hill | exist |
+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------+
```

I try to google the issue, but still have no clue; I think maybe some type conversion errors(TypeError: can't dup Fixnum ) cause this issue, but what exactly is this"dup Fixnum", how to solve them?
 
And ***one more thing also confused me*** is: I run the same code yesterday, and succeed loaded data into elasticsearch and I could also search them via localhost:9200, but next morning when I try the same thing(on the same cpmputer), I met these issues. I have tossed this a whole day, please help me get some hints.

Answer (score 2):

I also asked the same question on [logstash community](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/error-registering-plugin-pipeline-aborted-due-to-error-typeerror-cant-dup-fixnum-failed-to-execute-action/128987), with their help, I think I find the solution to my issue:
the exception trace `exception=>#<TypeError: can't dup Fixnum>` means there is a type conversion error. The sql_last_value which is initialized as 0 for numeric values or 1970-01-01 for datetime values. I think my `sql_last_value` stored in last_run_metadata_path is not the numeric or datetime value, so I add `clean_run => true` in conf file and run logstash again, no more error occurs. After `clean_run => true` was added, the wrong value of `sql_last_value` was reset to 0 or 1970-01-01 , the thread goes on and data be indexed successfully.